# Sub columns does not fit under wide grid column in ExtJs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

​If I have grid column in a ext grid, sub columns(​
Email and phone columns in the demo) does not match up.
Here is the demo : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5ih 
I have played with the width/minWidth etc but doesn't seem to work.
But if I make the grid column less wide sub columns seems to fit perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thin tha maybe the problem is that you must give the **minWidth** to fix the header, 
and add the **flex** property to each column. 
Here is the fork of your fiddle with the change I say.

```
minWidth : 500

flex : 1
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5iq

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the sub columns like the others, for example you have 2 columns which has fixed width, and the grouped columns should behave like columns with flex (**auto width**), you need to write an own function to do this resize.

It's only two lines: [sencha example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/iju)

**Description:** you need to add a `resize` event listener to grid and inside the function resize the sub column(s)

Grid listener:

```
listeners: {
    resize: function(grid) {
        // you need to add and itemId for the sub columns parent
        var subCols = grid.getView().getHeaderCt().child('#sub-cols');
        // 200 = sum of the fixed width of columns
        subCols.setWidth(grid.getWidth() - 200);
    }
}
```

Grid columns:

```
{
    text: 'sub columns',
    itemId: 'sub-cols',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
     }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        flex: 1
     }]
}
```